# Creating an template<T> only for such T that have operator/ defined

Tags: c++, templates, operators

I would like to define an `template<T>` for type, but I have to be sure that **only types that have `operator/` and `operator+` defined can be passed as `T`**.

It's because I want to be able to get interpolated value for two of them (that are of the same type), e.g.:

```
template<class T>
class Key final : public KeyBase{
public: //to keep the example simple
    //unsigned timeMS; <-- iherited from KeyBase
    T value;

public:
    Key(unsigned timeMS, const T &value) 
        : KeyBase(timeMS), value(value){}
    T inline getValue(){ return value; }
};

Key<float> start = {10, 5.0f};
Key<float> end = {15, 3.0f};
float ratioAtTime12 = 12 / (end.timeMS - start.timeMS);
float valueAtTime12 = start.value + (end.value - start.value) * ratio;

//Point2D is my own custom type that have operator+, - and / defined
Key<Point2D> start2 = {10, Point2D(10, 15)};
Key<Point2D> end2 = {15, Point2D(111, 6)};
...

Key<Character> start3 = {10, Character("Alan")}; //SHOULD generate an error
//because my custom Character type has no operator+, - or / defined!
```

For simple types like `float`, `int` etc. it's ok. But how to prevent using complex types as `T` **if they don't have `operator/` and `operator+` defined**?

Comment: If the mentioned operator gets used on an instance of a class where  it is not defined, you get a compilation error. so the type is constrained implicitly.

Comment: What do you want it to do if those operators aren't defined?

Comment: @GézaTörök I agree. However I would like to get an error in the moment I create such object (it's non-sense to even declare it from my point of view), rather then wait with it to the operator's usage.

Comment: @MarkB I would like to generate an compile-time error for the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a nice error message that doesn't include douzens of operators found via ADL or the like, you can define traits:

```
template <typename, typename=void>
struct isAddable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct isAddable<T, decltype(void(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>()))>
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename, typename=void>
struct isDividable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct isDividable<T, decltype(void(std::declval<T>() / std::declval<T>()))>
    : std::true_type {};
```

... and use a static assertion.

```
static_assert( isAddable<T>{} && isDividable<T>{}, "Invalid T!" );
```

Or, to get more specific information:

```
static_assert( isAddable<T>{}, "T not addable!" );
static_assert( isDividable<T>{}, "T not dividable!" );
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/fwUukj).

---

You can also use a handy macro to define such traits.

```
#define VAL std::declval<T>()

#define DEF_TRAIT(name, expression)                                  \
template <typename, typename=void> struct name : std::false_type {}; \
template <typename T>                                                \
struct name<T, decltype(void(expression))> : std::true_type {};

DEF_TRAIT(isDividable, VAL / VAL)
DEF_TRAIT(isAddable, VAL + VAL)
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/fWADC4).

Comment: That's fantastic :) Thank you for the detailed answer with the demo included, sir.

Comment: This checks if `T / T` and `T + T` is valid, but it fails for when the overload isn't made for two objects of the same type.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Irrelevant. The question states that *"It's because I want to be able to get interpolated value for two of them (**that are of the same type**),"*